# How to apply the texture on the model

Tags: texturing, uv

The sleeves have been correctly unwrapped, but why don't I see the texture applied?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have only opened the image in image editor but you haven't given your material the image texture.

[image: Give material image texture]

You can give your material image texture by clicking the yellow dot next to Base color and by choosing Image Texture.

[image: Open image]

Next press Open and find your image.

Comment: That was so easy, thanks.